# Upgraded to Sierra, cannot delete multiple lines

Tags: keyboard, macos

Recently upgraded to macOS Sierra, and since then I cannot delete multiple lines by pressing the Command key and Delete multiple times.

The first time I press command-Delete it deletes to the beginning of the current line, but pressing it again does nothing. In previous versions of macOS, pressing command-Delete again would delete the previous line also.

Comment: Delete multiple lines in _which_ app?

Comment: It doesn't work either in TextEdit nor in Visual Studio Code, so I assumed it was a broader issue.

Comment: In my experiments, Command-Delete deletes the text from the beginning of the line to the insertion point. Is this not what you are experiencing?

Comment: Yes, but if you keep holding Command and Press again Delete and Again and Again it will keep deleting lines right?, in my case it does not :(

Comment: In System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard tab, what value is set for Key Repeat? When I set this value to 'Off', what you are experiencing happens to me too.

Comment: I have it on `Fast` :-(

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be how ⌘-Delete behaves in Sierra. I don't know if there's a way to change it, but I'm inclined to believe it's simply how it behaves now.